# How can I check if a string ends with a particular substring in Liquid?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I know there is a `contains` keyword so I can use:

```
{% if some_string contains sub_string %}
    <!-- do_something -->
{% ... %}
```

But how can I check if a string ends with a particular substring?

I've tried this but it won't work:

```
{% if some_string.endswith? sub_string %}
    <!-- do_something -->
{% ... %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround you could use the `string slice` method

- with as `startIndex: some_string length - sub_string length`  and
- `stringLength: sub_string size`
- and if the result of the slice is the same as the sub_string -> the sub_string is at the end of some_string.

it's a bit clumpy in a liquid template but it would look like:

```
{% capture sub_string %}{{'subString'}}{% endcapture %}
{% capture some_string %}{{'some string with subString'}}{% endcapture %}

{% assign sub_string_size = sub_string | size %}
{% assign some_string_size = some_string | size %}
{% assign start_index = some_string_size | minus: sub_string_size %}
{% assign result = some_string | slice: start_index, sub_string_size %}

{% if result == sub_string %}
    Found string at the end
{% else %}
    Not found
{% endif %}
```

and if the some_string is empty or shorter than sub_string it works anyway because the slice result would be empty as well

Comment: Why are you using `capture` instead of `assign` ?

Comment: I am not sure actually. [Here](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/487) it says capture is/can be faster in some cases. I think `capture` makes sense for the some_string and sub_string definition because it could be something constructed from other things.  Perhaps for the rest `assign` would be clearer to read. What do you think?

Comment: In your case, with no `append`, like in `{% assign foobar = "foo" | append: bar %}`, the assign is 20% faster. From my point of view, when you can do with `assign`, this avoid you errors with unwanted spaces or line breaks.

Comment: Haven't tried this answer. I use other approach and avoided to check string endings in liquid code.

Answer (score 5):

With Jekyll, I ended up writing a small module-wrapper that adds a filter:

```rb
module Jekyll
   module StringFilter
    def endswith(text, query)
      return text.end_with? query
    end
  end
end
  
Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::StringFilter)
```

I use it like this:

```
{% assign is_directory = page.url | endswith: "/" %}
```

Comment: Docs on installing/creating plugins: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/installation/

Answer (score 3):

We can use another solution with `split` filter.

```
{%- assign filename = 'main.js' -%}
{%- assign check = filename | split:'js' -%}

{% if check.size == 1 and checkArray[0] != filename %}
   Found 'js' at the end
{% else %}
   Not found 'js' at the end
{% endif %}
```

Here we go ^^.

Comment: No, this is wrong ie. "mainjson.js" will fail in the first condition but does indeed end with "js"

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the answer by @v20100v

It would be best to get the last item in the array after splitting, as the string may have multiple occurrences of the separator.

e.g., "test_jscript.min.js"

Something like the below:

```
{% assign check = filename | split:'.' | last %}

{% if check == "js" %}
    Is a JS file
{% else %}
    Is not a JS file
{% endif %}
```